# unset proxy in a session can remove proxy from everywhere when proxy is configured in /etc/enviornment file

Tags: environment-variables, proxy

Suppose I have set proxy persistent way in my /etc/enviornment file and now I have run unset proxy from a session . So proxy will be there or not in this situation?
What I faced that even after unset proxy also though the proxy was defined their in the /etc/environment file it was behaving like proxy is present.
Can anyone please elaborate the proxy behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of proxy behaviour, but of environment variables.

You've set a var, let's assume `http_proxy`, using `/etc/environment`. The var will be present everywhere, on each tty, pts session, or GUI app (eg Chromium can only use a proxy but this variable on non DEs, Firefox can respect it or set a custom proxy).

If you `unset` a var on a pts session (a GUI terminal) it will apply to that session only. That means, unset will not be applied on other tabs (if you've got a tabbed terminal), or other terminal windows. If for example you open Chromium from that session/terminal (the one unset was executed) it won't have any proxy set.

An easy way is to just `echo $HTTP_PROXY` (and `$http_proxy`) and `echo $HTTPS_PROXY` and lower case also. If *none* of them is set, you have no proxy on that session. Beware of capital and lower case, they are different vars and could be both respected. Also both protocols, HTTP & HTTPS. Perhaps you missed some of these combinations.

Comment: ok, thank you for the brief explanation .. so suppose I am running an ansible where the requirement is proxy should be unset , in that case if I just unset the proxy from the session it will be enough for the ansible job (i mean tower-cli) or as the proxy details already present in the /etc/environment file so ansible will assume that proxy is still there?

Comment: @Priti I'm not acquainted with Ansible and can't tell you about it. Just give it a try.